# Expectation of Brownian motion and indicator function

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

I want to calculate the expression
$$
\mathbb{E}[B_t{1}_{\{B_t<a\}}]
$$
where $B_t$ is a standard Brownian motion, my instinct tells me that this is just
$$
\int_{-\infty}^a x\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\frac{x^2}{t}}\,dx=-e^{-\frac{a^2}{2t}}\sqrt{\frac{t}{2\pi}}.
$$
Is this right?

Comment: Yes, it is right.